# The MultiSet (Bag) Monad on FinHilb

Tags: ct.category-theory, quantum-mechanics, monads

It was recently brought to my attention that the Bag monad, also known as the MultiSet monad, [is not polynomial on Set](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/302631/what-is-the-polynomial-functor-for-the-bag-monad), but [is Polynomial on the category of Groupoids, 3.10 Examples](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1571066113000029?via%3Dihub).  I then started thinking about the category FinHilb, of finite-dimensional Hilbert spaces, and the fact that it has a dagger.   This allows for the fact that the subcategory of just unitary isomorphisms as morphisms, (ie the core of Hilb) is a groupoid.  I believe this means that the core of Hilb supports the polynomial functor of the Bag monad.  Can someone show the form of this polynomial monad, and perhaps talk a bit about this monad?

Comment: The trouble is that monads on groupoids are pretty uninteresting, since they are forced to be isomorphic to the identity monad.

Comment: it's polynomial in a 2-dimensional sense; you'd need a 2-category of Hilbert spaces.

Comment: Hi Todd, does that mean the trivial bag monad would be, like an empty bag?  It could have all the natural Isos $TT \rightarrow T$, $1 \rightarrow T$, but the bags are just empty?

Comment: I'm having difficulty making sense of the question. In ordinary language, I equate 'bag' to 'multiset' or to an element of a free commutative monoid; the analogous construct for a general monad would be a morphism $1 \to X$ of the Kleisli category. So a "trivial bag structure" of type $X$ I would have to translate as a morphism $1 \to X$ in the Kleisli category of the identity monad, which is just an element of $X$. But all of this is terribly unenlightening. I'd think you'd be much better off pursuing what Eduardo had in mind.